# Geometry question on Trapezoid.

Tags: geometry

The lengths of the bases of a trapezoid are represented by $x-10$ and $3x-8$. Express the length of the median of the trapezoid in terms of $x$.

Comment: The median's length is the average of the two base lengths:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The median of a trapezoid is given by the average of the lengths of its two bases.

So length of the median will be :
$$ \frac{1}{2}.(x-10+3x-8)$$
$$ \frac{1}{2}(4x-18)$$
$$ 2x-9$$